# The metadata specified for the identity provider does not contain an IDPSSODescriptor

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am working on adding custom policies in Azure ADB2C. I have followed all the step for adding the AD FS as an identity provider for this I have followed microsoft doc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

After all the step followed, during testing I got an exception message found using Application Insights

**"Message":"The metadata specified for the identity provider does not contain an IDPSSODescriptor."**

Please let me know if anyone knows the cause of this error and a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you either have an invalid metadata url or the metadata at the url is malformed or missing some key descriptors.

In your policy, the element with "PartnerEntity" key should have a valid url to the federation metadata document. Check that you can access this document normally from a browser, and that it contains the IDPSSODescriptor element.

```
<Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://your-AD-FS-domain/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml</Item>
```

This document should be publicly accessible over the internet as that's how B2C is going to reach it. If the document is missing any elements, then you may need to modify some ADFS settings to make sure all the required elements are there.

Comment: Yes it is missing the IDPSSODescriptor element, what settings do I need to modify on ADFS server for it to be resolved?

Comment: I think your question would better be directed on the ADFS forum. I am no ADFS expert, as far as I know this is a default metadata field that should always be there.